# What is wrong with this if statement logic in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic

```
if(stringName.charAt(0) != 'Q' || stringName.charAt(0) != 'W' || stringName.charAt(0) != 'E'){

        SetID = "Yes";

    }
```

The above code when I use alert to popup the windows the value of My.String.charAt(0) is returning the correct value but I don't know why it goes inside the if statement and change the value of SetID to `Yes`

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with it and really can't see anything

`SetID` is initialize to `No`

Comment: nipick: you really should store `stringName.charAt(0)` in a variable and use that instead of doing the look up multiple times.

Comment: @epascarello yes I did store it in my real code :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using `||` but you probably mean `&&` ...

The way it is now, it'll always be `true`. "If the character is not 'Q', or it's not 'W', or it's not 'E', then ..." — even if it is one of those characters, it will not be the others, so the expression evaluates to `true`.

Comment: OMG how stupid I'm really I should have thought of that logic once again.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down your statement.

```
MyString.charAt(0) != 'Q'
```

Okay, so if it's not Q then it continues.

```
||
```

So if the character *is* Q, continue along the chain.

```
MyString.charAt(0) != 'W'
```

By this point we've established that either the character is NOT Q (in which case `SetID = "Yes"` is run), or it is IS Q. But if it is Q, then clearly it is not W, therefore this next condition is true and `SetID = "Yes"` is run.

You see? No matter what the character is, it passes the test.

I think you meant to use `&&`, not `||`. If you use `&&`, then the `SetID = "Yes"` is only run if the character is NONE OF Q, W or E.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer [too much code for a comment], but another possible solution using a reg exp

```
var stringName = "Quick";
if( (/^[QWE]/).test(stringName) ){
   SetID = "Yes";
}
```